# How about a base class with a non-virtual destructor?

Tags: c++, new-operator, destructor

Can I use a class without a virtual destructor as a base class, if I declare the "operator new" in the child class private?

Can the following code cause runtime problems:

```
class B {
public:
    ~B() { }
};

class D: public B {
private:
    void* operator new(size_t);
}
```

Comment: Me no understand. Can you provide an example, or rephrase the question? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Using a non-virtual dtor in a class actually makes it a class that souldn't be derived (unless you like partially deleted objects...).

Comment: @JBL: No, it just makes it a class that shouldn't be deleted polymorphically. You can protect against that to some extent by making the destructor protected.

Comment: You might be better off having D contain a B rather than inheriting it. But of course it depends on what problem you're trying to solve here.

Comment: `class E: public D {
public:
    void* operator new(size_t);
}` "Oops, I wasn't allowed to extend that class?"

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson: Also nice one.

Comment: @MikeSeymour True, though I'd say that "it just makes it a class that shouldn't be deleted polymorphically" leads to "it shouldn't be derived" in my opinion. Though you may be extremely careful not to delete a pointer to base dynamically pointing at a derived, if other developers use the code, they might have a surprise...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still say `Base * p = ::new Derived;` and thus create a dangerous situation.

Comment: Yep, thank you, exactly the kind of... mmm... thing i was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a class with a non-virtual destructor as a base class regardless of how you override `operator new` in the derived classes.

The one thing that you have to be sure to avoid is using `delete` with a pointer to base if the instance being destroyed is of any derived type because this causes *undefined behavior*. Overriding `operator new` in a derived class doesn't change this fact.

Comment: Why would i want to delete with a pointer to an object that is not (or may be not) located on the heap? At least, that was the idea.

Comment: @dms: You don't, that would cause _undefined behavior_ straight away.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple set of guidelines for when you should make your destructor virtual

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/virtual-dtors.html

If you intend to prevent objects of the derived class from being constructed, then make the constructors private, not the `new` operator.

Comment: I guess the intention is to prevent the objects being created *dynamically*, not to prevent them being created at all.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ language does not *require* that a base class have a `virtual` destructor.  So, the direct answer to your question is "Yes,"  You **can** have a base class that doesn't have a virtual destructor.

However, you can't instantiate a derived object and `delete` is through a base class pointer without invoking Undefined Behavior.

```
class Base
{
};

class Derived
:
  public Base
{
  public:
    std::string mString;
};

Base* p = new Derived;
delete p;
```

You are `delete`ing a `Base` pointer, but the the dynamic type of `*p` is `Derived` and `Base` has no `virtual` destructor, so this invokes UB:

### 5.3.5/3 Delete

> In the first alternative (delete object), if the static type of the
>   operand is different from its dynamic type, the static type shall be a
>   base class of the operand’s dynamic type and the static type shall
>   have a virtual  destructor or the behavior is undefined. In the second
>   alternative (delete array) if the dynamic type of the object to be
>   deleted differs from its static type, the behavior is undefined.73)

You also can't employ trickery like this:

```
Base* p = new Derived;
Derived* d = dynamic_cast <Derived*> (p);
delete d;
```

...because you can only cast down the tree with `dynamic_cast` if the target is polymorphic -- meaning, has at least 1 `virtual` member -- which `Base` does not.

So, even though the direct answer to your question is "Yes," the *real* answer is, "Don't do that."

Comment: @CharlesBailey: That should be a little better.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual dtor is not a requirement for a base class, you certainly can do it with all defined results. And no need to using op new or anything.

The problem case related to the guideline is when delete is used on a pointer to base that points to instance of derived.

If your design ensures that deletion never happens that way, you can go ahead. Though it's a good idea to properly document this so future developers don't rush to "fix" the situation, or not break the rule.